# How generate Tests with evosuite on Ubuntu

Tags: java, jar, test-suite, evosuite

I tried to generate tests using evosuite standalone jar from commandline.

My project directory have source in src/czytacz and there is antlr-4.3-complete.jar in project directory

This is what I have do:
Copy evosuite jar to project directory.

Use command to setup evosuite for project:

> java -jar evosuite-0.1.1.jar -setup src/czytacz antlr-4.3-complete.jar

Use command to create tests:

> java -jar evosuite-0.1.1.jar -target src/czytacz

Output from evosuite:

> - EvoSuite
> - Found 0 matching classes in target src/czytacz
> - Analyzing classpath (generating inheritance tree)
>
>   - antlr-4.2-complete.jar
>   - src/czytacz

No Tests have been created for my project

-------------------------------edit---------------------------------

Thank you arcuri82 its solve my problem, but I have another.

For:

> krzysiek@krzysiek-Latitude-D630:~/git$ sudo java -jar
>   evosuite-0.1.1.jar -projectCP /home/krzysiek/workspace/czytacz -target
>   /home/krzysiek/workspace/czytacz/bin/czytacz

I get:

> - EvoSuite
> - Found 6 matching classes in target /home/krzysiek/workspace/czytacz/bin/czytacz
> - Analyzing classpath (generating inheritance tree)
>
>   - /home/krzysiek/workspace/czytacz
>   - /home/krzysiek/workspace/czytacz/bin/czytacz
> - Current class: Run
> - Going to generate test cases for class: Run
> - Starting client
> - Connecting to master process on port 9969
> - Analyzing classpath:
> - Inheritance tree loaded from /tmp/ES_inheritancetree2228980810912137439.xml.gz
> - Error while initializing target class: Target class not found in inheritance tree [MASTER] 12:37:11.978 [pool-1-thread-2] ERROR
>     TestSuiteGenerator - Problem for Run. Full stack:
>     java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Target class not found in
>     inheritance tree  at
>     org.evosuite.setup.DependencyAnalysis.analyze(DependencyAnalysis.java:85)
>     ~[evosuite-0.1.1.jar:na]  at
>     org.evosuite.TestSuiteGenerator.generateTestSuite(TestSuiteGenerator.java:221)
>     ~[evosuite-0.1.1.jar:na]  at
>     org.evosuite.rmi.service.ClientNodeImpl$1.run(ClientNodeImpl.java:125)
>     [evosuite-0.1.1.jar:na]   at
>     java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>     [na:1.8.0_45]     at
>     java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_45]
>     at
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     [na:1.8.0_45]     at
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     [na:1.8.0_45]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_45]
> - Computation finished [MASTER] 12:37:12.272 [main] ERROR SearchStatistics - No statistics has been saved because EvoSuite
>     failed to generate any test case [MASTER] 12:37:12.374 [main] ERROR
>     TestGeneration - failed to write statistics data

When I try to tests gwt project:

> krzysiek@krzysiek-Latitude-D630:~/git$ sudo java -jar
>   evosuite-0.1.1.jar -projectCP /home/krzysiek/planner/AghPlannerProject
>   -target /home/krzysiek/planner/AghPlannerProject/target/AghPlannerProject-1.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/classes

I get:

> - EvoSuite
> - Found 69 matching classes in target /home/krzysiek/planner/AghPlannerProject/target/AghPlannerProject-1.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/classes
> - Analyzing classpath (generating inheritance tree)
>
>   - /home/krzysiek/planner/AghPlannerProject
>   - /home/krzysiek/planner/AghPlannerProject/target/AghPlannerProject-1.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/classes
> - Current class: pl.edu.agh.planner.server.PlannerServiceImpl
> - Going to generate test cases for class: pl.edu.agh.planner.server.PlannerServiceImpl
> - Starting client
> - Connecting to master process on port 11775
> - Analyzing classpath:
> - Inheritance tree loaded from /tmp/ES_inheritancetree1562005591350926448.xml.gz
> - Could not find class under test: pl.edu.agh.planner.server.PlannerServiceImpl:
>     java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>     pl/edu/agh/planner/client/PlannerService
>     org.evosuite.instrumentation.InstrumentingClassLoader.instrumentClass(InstrumentingClassLoader.java:185)
>     org.evosuite.instrumentation.InstrumentingClassLoader.loadClass(InstrumentingClassLoader.java:139)
>     java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
>     java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
>     org.evosuite.Properties.getTargetClass(Properties.java:2086)
>     org.evosuite.Properties.getTargetClass(Properties.java:2060)
>     org.evosuite.setup.TestClusterGenerator.initializeTargetMethods(TestClusterGenerator.java:405)
>     org.evosuite.setup.TestClusterGenerator.generateCluster(TestClusterGenerator.java:171)
>     org.evosuite.setup.DependencyAnalysis.analyze(DependencyAnalysis.java:117)
>     org.evosuite.TestSuiteGenerator.generateTestSuite(TestSuiteGenerator.java:221)
>     org.evosuite.rmi.service.ClientNodeImpl$1.run(ClientNodeImpl.java:125)
>     java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>     java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>     java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>     pl/edu/agh/planner/client/PlannerService
>     java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
>     java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
>     java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:642)
>     org.evosuite.instrumentation.InstrumentingClassLoader.instrumentClass(InstrumentingClassLoader.java:178)
>     org.evosuite.instrumentation.InstrumentingClassLoader.loadClass(InstrumentingClassLoader.java:139)
>     java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
>     java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
>     org.evosuite.Properties.getTargetClass(Properties.java:2086)
>     org.evosuite.Properties.getTargetClass(Properties.java:2060)
>     org.evosuite.setup.TestClusterGenerator.initializeTargetMethods(TestClusterGenerator.java:405)
>     org.evosuite.setup.TestClusterGenerator.generateCluster(TestClusterGenerator.java:171)
>     org.evosuite.setup.DependencyAnalysis.analyze(DependencyAnalysis.java:117)
>     org.evosuite.TestSuiteGenerator.generateTestSuite(TestSuiteGenerator.java:221)
>     org.evosuite.rmi.service.ClientNodeImpl$1.run(ClientNodeImpl.java:125)
>     java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>     java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>     java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>     com/google/gwt/user/client/rpc/RemoteService
>     org.evosuite.instrumentation.InstrumentingClassLoader.instrumentClass(InstrumentingClassLoader.java:185)
>     org.evosuite.instrumentation.InstrumentingClassLoader.loadClass(InstrumentingClassLoader.java:139)
>     java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
>     java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
>     java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:642)
>     org.evosuite.instrumentation.InstrumentingClassLoader.instrumentClass(InstrumentingClassLoader.java:178)
>     org.evosuite.instrumentation.InstrumentingClassLoader.loadClass(InstrumentingClassLoader.java:139)
>     java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
>     java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
>     org.evosuite.Properties.getTargetClass(Properties.java:2086)
>     org.evosuite.Properties.getTargetClass(Properties.java:2060)
>     org.evosuite.setup.TestClusterGenerator.initializeTargetMethods(TestClusterGenerator.java:405)
>     org.evosuite.setup.TestClusterGenerator.generateCluster(TestClusterGenerator.java:171)
>     org.evosuite.setup.DependencyAnalysis.analyze(DependencyAnalysis.java:117)
>     org.evosuite.TestSuiteGenerator.generateTestSuite(TestSuiteGenerator.java:221)
>     org.evosuite.rmi.service.ClientNodeImpl$1.run(ClientNodeImpl.java:125)
>     java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>     java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>     java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>     com/google/gwt/user/client/rpc/RemoteService
>     java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
>     java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
>     java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:642)
>     org.evosuite.instrumentation.InstrumentingClassLoader.instrumentClass(InstrumentingClassLoader.java:178)
>     org.evosuite.instrumentation.InstrumentingClassLoader.loadClass(InstrumentingClassLoader.java:139)
>     java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
>     java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
>     java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:642)
>     org.evosuite.instrumentation.InstrumentingClassLoader.instrumentClass(InstrumentingClassLoader.java:178)
>     org.evosuite.instrumentation.InstrumentingClassLoader.loadClass(InstrumentingClassLoader.java:139)
>     java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
>     java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
>     org.evosuite.Properties.getTargetClass(Properties.java:2086)
>     org.evosuite.Properties.getTargetClass(Properties.java:2060)
>     org.evosuite.setup.TestClusterGenerator.initializeTargetMethods(TestClusterGenerator.java:405)
>     org.evosuite.setup.TestClusterGenerator.generateCluster(TestClusterGenerator.java:171)
>     org.evosuite.setup.DependencyAnalysis.analyze(DependencyAnalysis.java:117)
>     org.evosuite.TestSuiteGenerator.generateTestSuite(TestSuiteGenerator.java:221)
>     org.evosuite.rmi.service.ClientNodeImpl$1.run(ClientNodeImpl.java:125)
>     java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>     java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>     java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class
>     'com/google/gwt/user/client/rpc/RemoteService.class' should be in
>     target project, but could not be found!
>     org.evosuite.instrumentation.InstrumentingClassLoader.instrumentClass(InstrumentingClassLoader.java:185)
>     org.evosuite.instrumentation.InstrumentingClassLoader.loadClass(InstrumentingClassLoader.java:139)
>     java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
>     java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
>     java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:642)
>     org.evosuite.instrumentation.InstrumentingClassLoader.instrumentClass(InstrumentingClassLoader.java:178)
>     org.evosuite.instrumentation.InstrumentingClassLoader.loadClass(InstrumentingClassLoader.java:139)
>     java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
>     java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
>     java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:642)
>     org.evosuite.instrumentation.InstrumentingClassLoader.instrumentClass(InstrumentingClassLoader.java:178)
>     org.evosuite.instrumentation.InstrumentingClassLoader.loadClass(InstrumentingClassLoader.java:139)
>     java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
>     java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
>     org.evosuite.Properties.getTargetClass(Properties.java:2086)
>     org.evosuite.Properties.getTargetClass(Properties.java:2060)
>     org.evosuite.setup.TestClusterGenerator.initializeTargetMethods(TestClusterGenerator.java:405)
>     org.evosuite.setup.TestClusterGenerator.generateCluster(TestClusterGenerator.java:171)
>     org.evosuite.setup.DependencyAnalysis.analyze(DependencyAnalysis.java:117)
>     org.evosuite.TestSuiteGenerator.generateTestSuite(TestSuiteGenerator.java:221)
>     org.evosuite.rmi.service.ClientNodeImpl$1.run(ClientNodeImpl.java:125)
>     java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>     java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>     java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class
>     'com/google/gwt/user/client/rpc/RemoteService.class' should be in
>     target project, but could not be found!
>     org.evosuite.instrumentation.InstrumentingClassLoader.instrumentClass(InstrumentingClassLoader.java:171)
>     org.evosuite.instrumentation.InstrumentingClassLoader.loadClass(InstrumentingClassLoader.java:139)
>     java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
>     java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
>     java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:642)
>     org.evosuite.instrumentation.InstrumentingClassLoader.instrumentClass(InstrumentingClassLoader.java:178)
>     org.evosuite.instrumentation.InstrumentingClassLoader.loadClass(InstrumentingClassLoader.java:139)
>     java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
>     java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
>     java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:642)
>     org.evosuite.instrumentation.InstrumentingClassLoader.instrumentClass(InstrumentingClassLoader.java:178)
>     org.evosuite.instrumentation.InstrumentingClassLoader.loadClass(InstrumentingClassLoader.java:139)
>     java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
>     java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
>     org.evosuite.Properties.getTargetClass(Properties.java:2086)
>     org.evosuite.Properties.getTargetClass(Properties.java:2060)
>     org.evosuite.setup.TestClusterGenerator.initializeTargetMethods(TestClusterGenerator.java:405)
>     org.evosuite.setup.TestClusterGenerator.generateCluster(TestClusterGenerator.java:171)
>     org.evosuite.setup.DependencyAnalysis.analyze(DependencyAnalysis.java:117)
>     org.evosuite.TestSuiteGenerator.generateTestSuite(TestSuiteGenerator.java:221)
>     org.evosuite.rmi.service.ClientNodeImpl$1.run(ClientNodeImpl.java:125)
>     java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>     java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
> - Error while initializing target class: Failed to load pl.edu.agh.planner.server.PlannerServiceImpl [MASTER] 12:01:32.928
>     [pool-1-thread-2] ERROR TestSuiteGenerator - Problem for
>     pl.edu.agh.planner.server.PlannerServiceImpl. Full stack:
>     java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to load
>     pl.edu.agh.planner.server.PlannerServiceImpl  at
>     org.evosuite.setup.TestClusterGenerator.initializeTargetMethods(TestClusterGenerator.java:411)
>     ~[evosuite-0.1.1.jar:na]  at
>     org.evosuite.setup.TestClusterGenerator.generateCluster(TestClusterGenerator.java:171)
>     ~[evosuite-0.1.1.jar:na]  at
>     org.evosuite.setup.DependencyAnalysis.analyze(DependencyAnalysis.java:117)
>     ~[evosuite-0.1.1.jar:na]  at
>     org.evosuite.TestSuiteGenerator.generateTestSuite(TestSuiteGenerator.java:221)
>     ~[evosuite-0.1.1.jar:na]  at
>     org.evosuite.rmi.service.ClientNodeImpl$1.run(ClientNodeImpl.java:125)
>     [evosuite-0.1.1.jar:na]   at
>     java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>     [na:1.8.0_45]     at
>     java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_45]
>     at
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     [na:1.8.0_45]     at
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     [na:1.8.0_45]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_45]
> - Computation finished [MASTER] 12:01:33.127 [main] ERROR SearchStatistics - No statistics has been saved because EvoSuite
>     failed to generate any test case [MASTER] 12:01:33.230 [main] ERROR
>     TestGeneration - failed to write statistics data

Its seems that its can't find class but i don't know why, it is in pl/edu/agh/planner/client/

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify the classpath. The source folder (src/czytacz in your case) contains .java files. For the classpath you need to specify where the compiled .class files are. This depends on how you compiled your project (eg target/classes if you used Maven)